# Density of two independent uniform random variables in Mathematica

Tags: distributions, convolution

I've tried the following:

```
d1 = UniformDistribution[{0, W}];
d2 = UniformDistribution[{0, S}];
CDF[d1 + d2, x]
```

But I can't get it to work. I understand that the density will depend on if W < S or W >= S, but do I have no choice other than to specify numerical values for W and S?

Comment: @MarcoB 's answer is what you want.  But just to note if $W=S$, then you have the Irwin-Hall distribution and *Mathematica* implements that with `UniformSumDistribution` (which works with any number of terms to sum).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
uW = UniformDistribution[{0, W}];
uS = UniformDistribution[{0, S}];

tdist = 
  TransformedDistribution[
    d1 + d2,
    {Distributed[d1, uW], Distributed[d2, uS]}
  ];

CDF[tdist]
```

[image: screenshot of results for CDF]